# Asp.Net : Can't read fileName and post to AWS S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, asp.net-core, aws-sdk, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to .NET and I'm making a web api with asp.net. I'm trying to post a file to AWS S3 using the AWS .Net SDK.

It works but not if I try to read the fileName and send that as the key. It only works if I hardcode the key to a string (whereas I always want the key to be the same as the filename of the uploaded file).

When I try to read the filename from the file the error I'm getting is "Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed."

So far I'm just using Postman to POST the files. I set the "Content-Type" header to `multipart/form-data` but exactly the same thing happens if I set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

This is my UploadController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using BlogApi.Models;
using System.Web;
using awsTestUpload;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace BlogApi.Controllers
{
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class S3UploadController : ControllerBase
  {
    public S3UploadController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ListObjectsResponse GetAll()
    {
      var uploader = new AmazonUploader();
      return uploader.ListingObjectsAsync().Result;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PutObjectResponse MyFileUpload()
    {
      var request = HttpContext.Request;
      var fileStream = request.Body;
      var contentLength = request.ContentLength;
      string filePath = request.Form.Files.First().FileName;

      var length = contentLength.HasValue ? (long)contentLength : 0;

      var uploader = new AmazonUploader();
      return uploader.sendMyFileToS3(fileStream, filePath, length).Result;
    }
  }
}
```

and the Uploader class looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.S3.Transfer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace awsTestUpload
{
  public class AmazonUploader
  {
    public AmazonUploader() {
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

      Configuration = builder.Build();

      client = new AmazonS3Client(Configuration["aws:AWS_KEY"], 
      Configuration["aws:AWS_SECRET"], bucketRegion);
    }

    private IAmazonS3 client;
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
    private const string bucketName = "my-bucket-name"; 
    private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.EUWest2;

    public async Task<ListObjectsResponse> ListingObjectsAsync()
    {            
      ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
      {
        BucketName = bucketName
      };
      return await client.ListObjectsAsync(request);
    }
    public async Task<PutObjectResponse> sendMyFileToS3(System.IO.Stream inputStream, string fileNameInS3, long contentLength = 0)
    {
      PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
      {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = fileNameInS3,
        InputStream = inputStream
      };
      request.Headers.ContentLength = contentLength;
      return await client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    }
  }
}
```

When I debug and set a breakpoint, the value of filePath is a string matching the file name ( as I expect) but the upload is timing out. if I just set `filePath` to be a hardcoded string (ie replace `string filePath = request.Form.Files.First().FileName;` with `string filePath = "foo.png";`) it works fine.

Can anyone see why there's a difference?

Comment: This should be of some interest to you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Thanks yes that is helpful